# Timeline plotting: horizontal bars of time intervals

Tags: date-and-time, plotting

This text file logs the time that a process (identified by a number) changes state ("Brown", "Blue" etc.")

```
2014-08-29 03:59:52 , 27273 , Brown
2014-08-29 03:59:53 , 27276 , Green
2014-08-29 03:59:55 , 27276 , Brown
2014-08-29 03:59:57 , 27303 , Red
2014-08-29 03:59:58 , 27303 , Green
2014-08-29 03:59:59 , 27303 , Brown
2014-08-29 04:00:04 , 27317 , Brown
2014-08-29 04:00:07 , 27331 , Blue
2014-08-29 04:00:07 , 27334 , Blue
2014-08-29 04:00:08 , 27331 , Red
2014-08-29 04:00:08 , 27334 , Cyan
```

What I try to do is to plot horizontal bars as time intervals, colored according to the third column, where x-axis is time, y-axis is process id number. One of the colors (probably Cyan) should not be displayed, as it marks the interval end.

It is actually a timeline of many parallel events.

DatePlot does not seem to help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

```
dat = "2014-08-29 03:59:52 27273  Brown
       2014-08-29 03:59:53  27276  Green
       2014-08-29 03:59:55  27276  Brown
       2014-08-29 03:59:57  27303  Red
       2014-08-29 03:59:58  27303  Green
       2014-08-29 03:59:59  27303  Brown
       2014-08-29 04:00:04  27317  Brown
       2014-08-29 04:00:07  27331  Blue
       2014-08-29 04:00:07  27334  Blue
       2014-08-29 04:00:08  27331  Red
       2014-08-29 04:00:08  27334  Cyan";
 inputdata = ImportString[dat];
```

**DateListPlot**

```
ClearAll[dateListBars];
dateListBars[inpdata_, leftpadding_, rightpadding_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{datasets, dates, firstdate, lastdate,
   labels, colors, gdt, dlPltF, options,
   data = {#3, DateList[#1 <> " " <> #2], ToExpression@#4} & @@@ 
     inpdata},
  gdt = GatherBy[data, First];
  {labels, colors} = Transpose[{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 3]]} & /@ gdt];
  datasets = {#[[1, 1]], AbsoluteTime /@ #[[All, 2]], #[[All, 3]]} & /@
     gdt;
  dates = DeleteDuplicates@data[[All, 2]];
  {firstdate, lastdate} = DateList /@ ({leftpadding, rightpadding} +
      Through[{Min, Max}[AbsoluteTime /@ dates]]);
  dlPltF := DateListPlot[Thread[{{firstdate, lastdate}, #2[[1]]}],
     Joined -> True, Mesh -> {#[[2]]},
     MeshShading -> {White, Sequence @@ #[[3]], White},
     BaseStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.075], CapForm["Butt"]],
     Frame -> True, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0]] &;
  options = {PlotRange -> All, 
    GridLines -> {AbsoluteTime /@ dates, None},
    Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
    FrameTicks -> {{Thread[{Range[Length@datasets], labels}], None},
      {{AbsoluteTime@#, Rotate[DateString[#,
            {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}], Pi/2]} & /@
        {firstdate, Sequence @@ dates, lastdate}, None}},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{.5, .5}, {.5, .5}}};
  Show[MapIndexed[dlPltF, datasets], Sequence @@ options, opts]]


dateListBars[inputdata, -1, 5, ImageSize -> 600, LabelStyle -> 16] /. Cyan -> White
```

[image]

**BarChart**

Data preparation:

```
data = {#3, DateList[#1 <> " " <> #2], ToExpression@#4} & @@@ ImportString[dat];
{labels, colors} =  Transpose[{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 3]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, First]];
datasets = {#[[1,1]], AbsoluteTime /@ #[[All, 2]], #[[All, 3]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, First];
dates = DeleteDuplicates@data[[All, 2]];
{leftpadding, rightpadding} = {-1, 5};
{firstdate, lastdate} = DateList /@ ({leftpadding, rightpadding} +
                                      Through[{Min, Max}[AbsoluteTime /@ dates]]);
bcheights = 
  DateDifference[DateList[#1], DateList[#2], "Second"][[1]] & @@@ 
     Partition[#, 2, 
      1] & /@ (Append[Prepend[#, AbsoluteTime[firstdate]], 
       AbsoluteTime[lastdate]] & /@ datasets[[All, 2]] );
bccolors = Prepend[#, White] & /@ colors;
bcdata = Thread[Style[#, #2]] & @@@ Transpose[{bcheights, bccolors}];
```

Handling date ticks:

```
bcticks = Union[Flatten[Accumulate@# & /@ bcheights]];
bcticks = Thread[{bcticks, Rotate[DateString[
        DatePlus[firstdate, {#, "Second"}],
        {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}], Pi/2] & /@
     Union[Flatten[Accumulate@# & /@ bcheights]]}];
```

and the options

```
bcoptions = {ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left,
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[labels, Axis], None},
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], EdgeForm[]], 
   LabelStyle -> 16,
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, True}},
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {bcticks, None}},
   GridLines -> {bcticks[[All, 1]], None}, 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, ImageSize -> 600};


 BarChart[bcdata, bcoptions] /. Cyan -> White
```

[image]

**BulletGauge**

```
bgaugedata = 
  Transpose[{Accumulate /@ bcheights, Prepend[#, White] & /@ colors, 
    labels}];
Panel[Column[
   Reverse[BulletGauge[0, foo, Append[Prepend[#1 + 5, 0], 25],
         ScaleRangeStyle -> Thread[{#2, White}], GaugeMarkers -> None,
         GaugeLabels -> 
          Placed[Style[#3, "Subsubsection"], {2, Bottom}],
         ImageSize -> 600, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
         TicksStyle -> Opacity[0], ReferenceMarkerStyle -> Opacity[0],
         AspectRatio -> 1/10] & @@ # & /@ bgaugedata], 
   Spacings -> -2]] /. Cyan -> White
```

[image]

TODO: Date ticks ...

Comment: wow...this beautiful+1

Answer (score 8):

```
dat = "2014-08-29 03:59:52 27273  Brown
  2014-08-29 03:59:53  27276  Green
  2014-08-29 03:59:55  27276  Brown
  2014-08-29 03:59:57  27303  Red
  2014-08-29 03:59:58  27303  Green
  2014-08-29 03:59:59  27303  Brown
  2014-08-29 04:00:04  27317  Brown
  2014-08-29 04:00:07  27331  Blue
  2014-08-29 04:00:07  27334  Blue
  2014-08-29 04:00:08  27331  Red
  2014-08-29 04:00:08  27334  Cyan";
data = {DateList[#1 <> " " <> #2], #3, #4} & @@@ ImportString[dat];
{dates, val, col} = Transpose[data];
dlp = DateListPlot[MapThread[{{#1, #2}, {Last@dates, #2}} &, {Most@dates, Most@val}], 
     ImageSize -> 500, 
     PlotStyle -> (Thread[{Thickness[0.01],Most@(ToExpression /@ col)}]), PlotLegends ->    (Most@val), 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None}]
```

[image]

Note if, as the question suggest, the "values" are labels and the bars are desired to be equally spaced this could be done using `MapIndexed` rather than `MapThread`

Comment: Oooh right. Now I see what the OP meant :)

Comment: @Öskå happens to us all :)

Comment: @Öskå in the OP's question he specifically notes the last entry is end of interval and Cyan will not be needed...hence `Most` and no Cyan.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had to do some changes on the code, namely erased the "PlotLegends" and the "ImportString".

Comment: @user32916 I had changed your original data (omitting commas). kguler has posted a much better answer than mine

Answer (score 2):

With `se.dat` being exactly what you provided:

```
dat = StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ Import["~/se.dat", "List"];
dates = ToExpression /@ 
          (StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ 
            (StringReplace[StringTrim@#, {"-" | " " | ":" -> ","}] & /@ First /@ dat))
val = ToExpression[#[[2]]] & /@ dat
col = ToExpression[#[[3]]] & /@ dat
DateListPlot[List /@ Thread@{dates, val}, PlotStyle -> col]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]